# How do you calculate the sum of integer elements in an array using text files in Java?

Tags: java, text, sum, file-handling, java-io

Lets say I have a "Scores.txt" file containing 2 or more arrays.

**Example**

```
10 20 30 40 50 //sum is 150
11 21 31 41 51 //sum is 155
```

I want to be able to read each elements in a line and add them up together.

Also follow up questions. What is the correct way to write an array of integers into a text file? How do you separate each elements but still place them in one line?

This is the code I'm using to write the arrays but I have a feeling that there might be issues when reading the elements.

**write() code**

```
      try {
         File file = new File ("Scores.txt");
         BufferedWriter bWrite = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file, true));

         int score[] = new int [5];

         System.out.println("Enter scores: ");
         for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            score[i] = sc.nextInt();
         }

         for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            bWrite.write(score[i] + " ");
         }
         bWrite.flush();
         bWrite.close();

      }
      catch (Exception e) {
         System.out.println("ERROR");
      }
```

Comment: Read the entire line then do string.split(" ") to get the array of values.

Comment: Your `write()` code will write everything on one line because `BufferedWriter` only starts a new line when you call `newLine()`.  But if that code is the entire body of your `write()` routine, you won't be able to write _multiple lines_ of data to the file by calling `write()` in its current form multiple times, because each call to `write()` creates a new empty `Scores.txt` that overwrites the previous file.